# Custom log4j appender is not found in my Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, log4j, sentry

I try to use a custom appender (sentry-raven) for log4j in my Eclipse plugin project but log4j can't find it. The jar file (raven-log4j-7.8.6.jar) includes the missing appender ("com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender") but Eclipse's class loader cannot find it.

This is what I have done so far:

- I put the jar file in a /lib folder under my project root
- My plugin manifest have the entries `Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: org.apache.log4j`, `Require-Bundle: org.apache.log4j` and `Bundle-ClassPath: lib/, .`

My `build.properties` looks like

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               plugin.xml,\
               .,\
               lib/raven-7.8.6.jar,\
               lib/raven-log4j-7.8.6.jar
```

I add the following code in my `start(BundleContext context)` method of my plugin to have better control when the log4j property file gets loaded.

```
URL installURL = getBundle().getEntry("/");
String installPath = Platform.asLocalURL(installURL).getFile();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(installPath +"/src/log4j.properties");
```

I get the following error as soon as the debugger steps over the last code line.

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender cannot be found by org.apache.log4j_1.2.15.v201012070815
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
...
```

The log4j.properties looks like

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, default, Sentry
log4j.appender.Sentry=com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender
..
```

Answer (score 0):

From the OSGI specification itself:

> The Bundle-ClassPath header defines a comma-separated list of JAR file path names or directories
>   (inside the bundle) containing classes and resources.

You'll need to explicitly list the raven jar files.

Answer (score 0):

I removed org.apache.log4j from Manifest=>Dependencies and manually added log4j-1.215.jar (saved it to lib folder and added the jar file under Manifest=> Runtime => Classpath)

Then my custom appender worked.